# Importing Biopython does not work in Jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab, biopython, python-3.9

I wish to use biopython in Jupyter lab.
I work with Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with a Python3.9.5 64-bit kernel in Jupyter lab.

Importing biopython with the following commands work well in a Python terminal:

```
from Bio import Phylo
import Bio
```

However, these commands do not work in Jupyter lab with a Python3.9.5 64-bit kernel.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'
```

Do anyone know what could be the cause of this problem which affect Jupyter lab?

Comment: Whatever environment is backing your JupyterLab doesn't have Biopython installed. In a cell in your notebook in JupyterLab, run `%pip install biopython` if you mainly use `pip` to manage your packages. If you use mainly anaconda / conda, then use in a cell in a notebook in JupyterLab, `%conda install -c conda-forge biopython`. The modern magic commands will insure the installation occurs in the environment backing the notebook you are using in JupyterLab. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more info.

Comment: Thank you @Wayne. As mentioned in the link you provided, the conda command is not working here, but pip install has worked perfectly.  I keep preciously your link

Comment: Glad to hear the `%pip install` route got you past that hurdle. Having some options can make it easier sometimes than sorting out the environment intricacies.